# How do you get URL parameters from react-router outside components to use in GraphQL query

Tags: reactjs, react-router, graphql

Is it possible to access the URL params supplied in a route outside the components?

This of course can be accomplished with `window.location` but I am looking for something in the react-router API to do this more cleanly.

Additionally, if there is a more standard approach to doing this with GraphQL, that's even better! I am just looking into browser clients for gql and new to gql in general.

Example component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { graphql } from 'react-apollo';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import get from 'lodash.get';

const ContractComponent = (props) => {
    ...
};

const ContractQuery = gql`query ContractQuery ($contractId: String!){
  contract(id: $contractId) {
    ...
  }
}`;

const ContractWithData = graphql(ContractQuery, {
  options: { variables: { contractId: contractId } }, // <-- var i want to pull from url params
})(ContractComponent);

export default ContractWithData;
```

Example route:

```
<Route path="contract/:contractId" component={Contract} />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really familiar with react-apollo, but I think the following is a good way to achieve what you want. 
You can see in the docs that `options` can be a function taking the component props as input, returning an object with the options: http://dev.apollodata.com/react/queries.html#graphql-options

So I think you can do:

```
const ContractWithData = graphql(ContractQuery, {
    options: props => ({ variables: { contractId: props.params.contractId } })
})(ContractComponent);
```

In the code above, `props.params` are the params passed by react-router to the route component (nothing special there).

You want to write `options` as a function when you need do to something dynamic at runtime, in this case accessing the route params.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yep, that did the trick. I missed that in the docs, thanks for finding that!